# Adding a column to a Farpoint Spread grid

Tags: vb.net, excel, grid, spread, farpoint

I've never really used Farpoint Spread before, but I have an existing VB.NET application in which I need to add a column to a Spread grid.  There is currently some code like:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In g_AdoRS.Rows
    vaSpreadSum.SetText(1, x, dr(0))    'pol_ser
    ...
    vaSpreadSum.SetText(20, x, dr(19))    'renew_pay_cd     
    vaSpreadSum.SetFloat(21, x, dr(20))    'renew_tot_prem
    vaSpreadSum.SetFloat(22, x, dr(21))    'renew_pol_limit
    vaSpreadSum.SetFloat(23, x, dr(22))    'renew_ded_amt

    vaSpreadSum.Col = 28
    x = x + 1
Next dr
```

These SetFloat() and SetText() calls go from 0 to 28. So in order to add another column I added this line of code:

```
vaSpreadSum.SetText(28, x, dr(27))    'agent name
```

and changed the vaSpreadSum.Col to 29

```
vaSpreadSum.Col = 29
```

But I am not seeing another column in my grid. Any idea why?  There is no error thrown or anything like that, just no changes on the screen.  I know there is probably more information needed to solve this, but even if anyone know the basics of adding a column to a Farpoint Spread grid that would be much appreciated.  I found [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/SpreadNet7/ASP2/webframe.html#spweb-RowColAdd.html) but it doesn't seem that my application is adding columns that way, I couldn't find any calls to the AddColumns() method anywhere.

Thanks for any help!

I believe this is my Form_Load method

```
Private Sub FrmDetailRPC_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

    FormInit()
    QryLocation()

    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

I'll also include FormInit() because that sounds like it might have to do with what I'm looking for

```
Sub FormInit()
    txtBusUnit.Text = svBusUnit
    stmtMktSeg()
    txtProduct.Text = svProduct
    txtSource.Text = svSource
    txtSystem.Text = svSystem
    txtCustSeg.Text = svCustSeg

    stmtProduct()

    txtLocation.Text = svLocation
    If svLocationLabel = "Region" Then
        lblLocation.Text = "Territory"
    Else
        lblLocation.Text = svLocationLabel
    End If

    lblLocation.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight

    stmtLocation()
    'txtPayType.Text = svPayType
    txtTimePer.Text = TimeName
    stmtTimePer()

End Sub
```

And QryLocation()

```
Sub QryLocation()
    Dim producerID As String

    'SetProductSelection()
    stmtLocation()
    stmtGetProductType()
    stmtGetTimePeriodType()
    stmtGetTimePeriod()
    stmtGetProducerID()
    stmtGetProducerType()

    If stmtProducerType = "No Preference" Then
        producerID = "NULL"
    Else
        producerID = "'" & stmtProducerID & "'"
    End If

    g_strSQL = "pc_mis_rpc_getdata_detail " & _
    "'" & stmtLocationType & "'," & _
    "'" & Trim(svLocation) & "'," & _
    "'" & svBusUnit & "'," & _
    "'" & stmtProductType & "'," & _
    "'" & Trim(stmtProductDtl) & "'," & _
    "'" & stmtTimePeriod & "'," & _
    "'" & stmtTimePeriodType & "'," & _
    "'" & stmtProducerType & "'," & _
    producerID & "," & _
    "'Retention'" _
    & FilterQry & "," & _
    "'" & Trim(txtCustSeg.Text) & "'," & _
    "'" & Trim(txtSource.Text) & "'," & _
    "'" & Trim(txtSystem.Text) & "'"


    ProcQry()

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know if the grid was created with the designer originally? If so, there should be something in the form's generated code that tells the spread control how many columns and rows exist. You can also look at the form designer, click on the spread control, hit F4 to see properties for the control, and check to see if rows and columns are defined there.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was made with the designer, I don't have access to it apparently, since I only have the standard license.  I added a lot of the code that I think generates the grid to my post above.

Comment: That code does not change the number of columns. It is only for when a click occurs in the spreadsheet. Would you post your Form_Load code please?

Comment: There is no method exactly called "Form_Load" but I believe what I added to my original post is what you're referring to.

Comment: Would you also post FormInit and QryLocation too please?

Comment: Done. Sorry, should have figured those would be important.

Comment: I am not seeing what I am looking for. I think I know the correct syntax.  Let me add the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Form_Init()` you will need to adjust the number of columns in spread control.

It should look something like this:

```
Sub FormInit()
    ' Add a column to the spreadsheet control
    vaSpreadSum.ActiveSheet.AddColumns(29, 1)

    ' Code cut for brevity
End Sub
```

--or--

```
Sub FormInit()
    ' Add a column to the spreadsheet control
    vaSpreadSum.ActiveSheet.Columns.Count = 29

    ' Code cut for brevity
End Sub
```

Another method for achieving the same thing is to open the form designer, select the spread control, display the properties window (press F4 if it isn't already open), and increase the Cols property to 29.

Comment: Says 'Cols is not a member of AxFPSpreadADO.AxfpSpread'  'Col' seems to not throw an error, think its the same?

Comment: Just tried it with Col and it gave me a null reference exception

Comment: No. Try Columns instead of Cols. I don't have the documentation in front of me so I am trying to remember what the correct property name should be.

Comment: Doesn't like Columns or Column either. Is there documentation for this? I've been looking all over and haven't been able to find any.

Comment: http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/SpreadNet7/WF/webframe.html#FarPoint.Win.Spread~FarPoint.Win.Spread.SheetView~AddColumns.html

Comment: Yeah, I've been there. I guess I'm just not sure where to go from there. Nothing looks familiar...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48301/discussion-between-adam-zuckerman-and-inta)

Comment: Sorry, I had to get up for a bit. Also, I'm at work and can't access the chat. I will let you know how this new code goes when I try it in a minute.

Comment: I get an error with both, saying either "'AddColumns' is not a member of 'Short'" or "'Columns' is not a member of 'Short'"  Col or Cols also does not work.

Comment: Did you try opening the form designer?

Comment: Yeah. I cannot see the grid within the form designer. I imagine that's what the Farpoint designer would be used for.

Comment: Do you want me to look at the whole form? You could email it to me.  I'll add my email to my profile's About Me if you want to do that.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to be getting access to the designer so that should hopefully solve my problem. Thank you for all your help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You increase the column as follows:
vaSpreadSum.MaxCols = 29